# Laravel - count() through belongsToMany of a hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel-4

I've got stucked in my Laravel project and can't get my head around a problem accuring.

**Explanation**
In my app, there are 3 tables: xCodes, Postings and Users.
A xCode has many Postings - Every Posting belongs to many subscribed Users, who get notified about changes.

*Model XCode.php*

```
public function postings(){
    return $this->hasMany('Posting');   
}
```

*Model Posting.php*

```
public function subscribers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');    
}

public function xcode(){
        return $this->belongsTo('XCode','x_code_id');   
}
```

*Model User.php*

```
public function subscriptions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Posting'); 
}
```

**Problem**
How can I manage displaying the numbers of Postings the current User has subscribed to for each xCode? Something like

```
$xcode->postings->subscribers->where(Auth::user()->id)->count()
```

doesn't work here...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the proper syntax to use for the count assuming you're declaring it in User model is: $this->postings->subscribers()->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->count();

Comment: Allready tried that. Returns error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$subscribers

Comment: yea, after reviewing your relationships again that'll not work, how does your User relate to the xCode model?

Comment: I think that is the main problem: A User doesn't relate to the xCode model directly. Many Users can have many Postings - A Posting belongs to a xCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I found for myself:

```
    public function count_subscribers($user_id){

    //get a list of all posting-ids associated to the User
    $posting_ids = DB::table("posting_user")->where('user_id',$user_id)->lists('posting_id');
    //get all Postings where current xCode is associated with
    return DB::table('postings')->whereIn('id',$posting_ids)->where('x_code_id',$this->id)->count();

}
```

I don't know if that is the most elegant way to solve this, but it works :)